# How to login to my Stellar Accout

Tags: accounts

I know my Stellar account was upgraded many many months ago, but I can't seem to figure out how to login to view my account.

When I go to https://accountviewer.stellar.org/, I see 4 options for me to choose from.

- Connect with Albedo
- Connect with Ledger
- Connect with Freighter
- Connect with Trezor

  But I don't have the login for any of these accounts.

  Does anyone have any idea how I can login?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a login for the original account, which is at the following address: https://launch.stellar.org/#/login

You'll need to upgrade from there.

However, there is currently an issue with that site and it's showing a generic error message when people have logged in and not showing public/private keys or balance anymore. Someone else has asked a question about this also, so just waiting on someone with more knowledge on this to answer or resolve. I've tried asking on various forums but without any replies as yet.

Comment: Unfortunately, as you said above, I'm also not able to login to the launch.stellar.org site even though I have the key.  It gave an error which someone else has also encountered and has posted the question which remains unanswered.

Comment: Where is the other question you reference that was asked about this? I'm having this issue. I'm able to log in, but I'm not given a secret or public key due to some browser issue, so I can't upgrade my account.

Comment: It's a question titled "I do not see the public key and the private key to update" . Seems that quite a few people are unable to upgrade their accounts due to this issue. No one has responded on any forums yet.